# Iterating through Twitch Json

Tags: json, vb.net, iteration, twitch

I'm not very good at this yet, not sure if my subject even accurately describes what I need. I know it's probably been answered, I'm having a hard time understanding the answers since they don't directly apply to my data. I am trying to figure out how I can iterate through the data in this URL.

http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/twitch/chatters

This is what I've been using.

```
Dim url = "http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/" & ConnectionInformation.Channel.TrimStart("#") & "/chatters"
Dim json As String = Nothing
Dim wc As New WebClient()
json = wc.DownloadString(url)

Dim root As JToken = JToken.Parse(json)
For Each item As JToken In root("chatters")
'I've tried several things here and I can't find a good way to iterate through the viewers found here.        
Next
```

I guess I'm having trouble getting the viewers in a collection so that I can iterate through them, can someone point me in the right direction here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Chatters" is actually a Type in the root object.  If you were to create classes, they would look like this:

```
Public Class RootChatter
    Public Property _links As _Links
    Public Property chatter_count As Integer
    Public Property chatters As Chatters
End Class

Public Class _Links
End Class

Public Class Chatters
    Public Property moderators As String()
    Public Property staff As String()
    Public Property admins As String()
    Public Property global_mods As String()
    Public Property viewers As String()
End Class
```

Viewers is an array in the Chatters Property (`Root.Chatters.Viewers`).  Without the class:

```
Dim root As JToken = JToken.Parse(jstr)
Dim chatters = root("chatters")("viewers")

For n As Integer = 0 To chatters.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine(chatters(n))
Next
```

Output:

> 04paynem
>   0morningstar0
>   0rchlann
>   0riginus
>   10108abc

If you were to deserialize to the classes:

```
Dim jc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootChatter)(jstr)
Dim viewers = jc.chatters.viewers
```

Comment: This should be an incredible help. It even helps to explain what some of the other threads were talking about. I didn't realize I was seeing 2 ways of skinning the cat.

Comment: I think it always helps to view it the class format to understand the relationships etc, even if you are going to use `JToken.Parse`.  It just seems easier to me to read than the encoded JSON string.  If you copy your JSON to the clipboard, **Edit Menu - Paste Special - Paste JSON as Classes** will create the classes for you - sometimes you have to tweak stuff, but it gives you a quick starting point.

Comment: Yea it does help to see those relationships, you lost me about the edit menu though. Are you talking about inside the Visual Studio? I don't see these Paste special options.

Comment: If you have a JSON string (data) on the clipboard, VS will create the classes from the string.  Maybe it is not in your version - I have 2012, but not sure when it was added.  http://jsonutils.com/ is an online converter - VB or C# classes